# Missing files using Xampp

Tags: 14.04, apache2, xampp

I have installed xampp in my ubuntu 14.04 and i want to know why i cant found the files like apache2.conf or conf-available. I cant found /etc/apache2....

Anyone know why it is happening?

Thanks

Comment: If you install XAMPP from the downloaded distribution instead of installing apache etc. from the ubuntu repositories, it will usually be installed under /opt/lampp (see [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/XAMPP/))

Comment: yes, i know it, but inside there arent the files i said laik apache2.conf or conf-available

Comment: What about `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`?

Comment: yes, this file exists....but the others? :S

Comment: XAMPP seems not to follow the default apache2 configuration scheme. Look into httpd.conf; maybe there are hints to other configuration files. If not, all configuration might be done in this one file...

Answer (score 0):

You should read the Ubuntu [server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf). It will probably answer most of your beginner questions on getting your web server setup (including the question you asked, which the guide states is in `/etc/apache2/`).

See http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DistrosDefaultLayout for discussion of where you might find Apache httpd configuration files on various platforms, since this can vary from release to release and platform to platform. The most common answer, however, is either /etc/apache/conf or /etc/httpd/conf

Generically, you can determine the answer by running the command:

> `/opt/lampp/bin/httpd -V    or       httpd -V`

(That's a `capital V`). Or, on systems where httpd is renamed, perhaps `apache2ctl -V`

This will return various details about how httpd is built and configured, including the default location of the main configuration file.

One of the lines of output should look like:

```
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

which, combined with the line:

```
-D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
```

will give you a full path to the default location of the configuration file

Comment: i have answered that i havent an apache2 in /etc. I have made the installation directly with the instalator of XAMPP

Comment: xampp doesn't have apache2 in etc.. instead its located in /opt/lampp

there you can find httpd.conf

Comment: yeah,thats right, but where can i find files like apache2.conf or conf-available?

Comment: why do you want this files so badly

Comment: can you tell us your purpose

Answer (score 0):

Xampp does not use the Debian-style configuration conventions. It uses a more traditional configuration. Forget about `a2enmod`, `a2ensite` and the rest; read the [Xampp documentation](https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_linux.html).